# how to properly bundle and import css with rollup react - Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules

Tags: reactjs, rollup, postcss

I have a react app (next.js) and a react component library.

In my library, I have a couple css module imports from 3rd party libraries (i.e. tailwind and fontsource) which are causing issues in my next.js app when I import my lib.

> error - ./node_modules/tailwindcss/tailwind.css Global CSS cannot be
> imported from within node_modules. Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm

**output-filename.cjs.development.js**

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

function _interopDefault (ex) { return (ex && (typeof ex === 'object') && 'default' in ex) ? ex['default'] : ex; }

var React = require('react');
var React__default = _interopDefault(React);
require('tailwindcss/tailwind.css'); // << next.js complains
require('@fontsource/titillium-web/index.css'); // << next.js complains
...
```

Is there a way to configure rollup to build these as local css files i can include in the build, and if so, how do I import them in the react library code? I have tried adding extract: true to postcss config but it doesn't seem to generate everything properly (all the styles are missing in the .css file) and I'm not sure how to import them.

**rollup config (via tsdx.config.js)**

```
const postcss = require('rollup-plugin-postcss')
module.exports = {
  rollup(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: './postcss.config.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.css'],
        minimize: true,
        inject: {
          insertAt: 'top'
        },
        extract: true
      })
    )
    return config
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same exact problem.

Comment: @Gab so far the best I can come up with is just importing the css in each component rather than globally.